# Does node.js memory usage increase as the number of simultaneous requests increase, or is this a leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I have the following node.js code running:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.write("Hello");
res.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

When I start the server (by typing `node myFile.js`), the node process is using 9MB of memory.

Then I created the following webpage which I open in several tabs in my web browser, so I simultaneously make requests to node:

```
<html>
    <head>
                <script>
                    var ajax = {};
        var questions = [];
        var questionsResponses = [];

        ajax.x = function() {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
                return new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            var versions = [
                "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",
                "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",
                "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
                "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
            ];

            var xhr;
            for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
                try {
                    xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                    break;
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            return xhr;
        };

        ajax.send = function(url, callback, method, data, async) {
            var x = ajax.x();
            x.open(method, url, async);
            x.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (x.readyState == 4) {
                    if (x.status == 200) {
                        callback(x.responseText)
                    } else {
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
            };
            if (method == 'POST') {
                x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            }
            x.send(data)
        };

        ajax.get = function(url, data, callback, async) {
            var query = [];
            for (var key in data) {
                query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
            }
            ajax.send(url + '?' + query.join('&'), callback, 'GET', null, async)
        };

        ajax.post = function(url, data, callback, async) {
            var query = [];
            for (var key in data) {
                query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
            }
            ajax.send(url, callback, 'POST', query.join('&'), async)
        };


                var count = 0;
        function sayHello(){
            ajax.get("http://localhost:8888", {}, sayHello, true); 
            var heading = document.getElementById("c");
            while (heading.firstChild) {
                heading.removeChild(heading.firstChild);
            }
            var countText = document.createTextNode(""+count++);
            heading.appendChild(countText);
        }

            </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="c"></h1>
        <script>        sayHello();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The memory that node is using now is 46.2 MB. It slowly increases. Every once in a while there is a jump, and then it continues to slowly increase. Is this normal behavior of node when getting many simultaneous requests, or is this a leak ?

EDIT: Seems to be stable at 46.4 MB. But I don't know whether it is stable because the number of requests I make are limited (since I'm opening multiple tabs in my web browser), so this could just be a limitation of my laptop. XD

EDIT: The memory increase seems to happen even if I make only one request at a time (ie. opening one tab only in my web browser). Also, even after closing all the windows, the memory used doesn't decrease (it remains at 46.4 MB).

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is proportionality between the number of requests and the memory usage: every request needs some objects (ex.: req, res, ...) to be handled and every object takes memory.
In my nodejs applications I noted that with the increasing of requests the memory increases as well but sometimes it falls down under the action of the Google V8 Engine Garbage Collector which is very efficient.
Anyway, the memory leaks are behind the corner but for sure it's not possible to speak about memory leak for memory usage around 50 MB as the one you are speaking about.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious. More request you get, more memory your application will be using to manage the flow of accepting request and responding.

I think you are asking this for an issue of scalability.
You should design your code without storing data in memory but with a single logical database, so that many instances of the same application can run on different machines. If one server's memory limit is reached, you just start your application also on a new machine and redirect overreaching traffic there. Because database is one and shared among various instances. Some cloud provider for hosting nodejs application (openshift, heroku) do this automatically: your code is running on a single 'cartridge', if too much traffic arrives they start your application on supplementary cartridges and balances the traffic among various cartridge. So that it never stop because of too much memory or CPU usage.